# Some simple but strange problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have this date picker:

```
<label for="bday" style="text-align:right">Pick Date</label>
<input type="date" name="bday" id="bday">
```

i try to put any date - But without success

i try this: `$('#bday').val(Date.now("dd/mm/yyyy"));` - but i see only numbers

another problem, i have comboBox that fill with numbers from 1 to 10:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain" >
<label for="select-choice-1" class="select" style="text-align:right">Pic Num</label>
<select name="select-choice-1" id="ZIBI">
</select>
</div>
```

when i pick the first number - He does not show on the control

and when i force any selection like this:  `$('#ZIBI').val("31");` - He does not show on the control

thanks

Comment: These are two separate questions.

Comment: You need to state your problems clearly, and if you have two different problems that aren't connected, you can't just roll them together into one question and give a title that doesn't describe either one.

Answer (score 0):

When i want to get the date I do something like this:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getYear();

//Show it
document.write(day, month, year);
```

I hope it helps you.